# Ayuda con la validacion de una mask de un input de nombre en JS

Tags: jquery, html5

Poseo un input el cual estoy validando que solo ingrese letras,aunque el mismo funciona, también me restringe la tecla "barra espaciadora". Soy bastante nuevo en el uso de esta herramienta, no se como añadirle esa tecla a la consulta en caso de que el usuario decida colocar dos o más nombres.

```html
$("#nombre").mask('SSSSSSSSSSS');
```

Comment: Hola FJAL, Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para observar mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y así ganar tu primera medalla! También te invito a revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo!

Comment: Por favor agrega el código necesario como para reproducir el problema y así poder depurar. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la [documentación oficial](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#translation), puedes definir las máscaras como tú quieras, pasando las opciones como segundo parámetro:

```js
$('#texto').mask('AAAAAAAA',{
  translation: {
    A: {pattern: /[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúü ]/} //todas las letras inglesas más la ñ y vocales acentuadas 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input id="texto" type="text">
```